# check existing data visual basics macro

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am struggling with my macro to check existing data.

My table is Excel is as follows:
Cells (D2:D13) contains user input prompts like Name, Surname, Address, Telephone number etc.
Cells (E2:E13) is where the corresponding data is input by the user

Then I have a table in cells (C17:O17) for the database to store the input from cells(E2:E13)

Then I have a button assigned to a Macro but the **code doesn't work properly**.

The part of my code I am struggling with:

```
        If Cells(i, 3) = Range("E2") And Cells(i, 4) = Range("E3") Then
        Range("E4") = Cells(i, 5)
        Range("E5") = Cells(i, 6)
        Range("E6") = Cells(i, 7)
        Range("E7") = Cells(i, 8)
        Range("E8") = Cells(i, 9)
        Range("E9") = Cells(i, 10)
        Range("E10") = Cells(i, 11)
        Range("E11") = Cells(i, 12)
        Range("E12") = Cells(i, 13)
        Range("E13") = Cells(i, 14)
        Exit Sub
        End If
Next i
MsgBox "Record doesn't exist"
```

In the first line of code is my problem. If I just enter the first part:

```
If Cells(i, 3) = Range("E2")
```

the code works but when I try add the second part:

```
And Cells(i, 4) = Range("E5") Then
```

the code stops working and rather skips both parts of the code to execute:

```
Next i
MsgBox "Record doesn't exist"
```

How do I get   And Cells(i, 4) = Range("E5") part of the code to work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following the pattern on your references you should probably change `Range("E5")` to `Range("E3")` in your `If` condition so it becomes

```
If Cells(i, 3) = Range("E2") And Cells(i, 4) = Range("E3") Then
```

**Side note** Using `Transpose()` worksheet function your `If` statement could be simplified to

```
If Cells(i, 3) = Range("E2") And Cells(i, 4) = Range("E3") Then
    Range("E4").Resize(10, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Cells(i, 5).Resize(1, 10))
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo it is actually Range("E3") in my code but that still does not work for some reason. I will quickly go edit the code I posted. Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot of D2:O17. We need to see the data contained in these cells. If for example they are strings there might be some extra spaces that you cannot see, in which case you could use `Trim()` funtion.

Comment: I added screenshot called check existing data picture

Comment: Ok, now what is it exactly you want to do? (a) Enter Name and search, (b) enter Surname and search or (c) enter both Name and Surname and search?

Comment: I did try using the code you suggested :  If Cells(i, 3) = Range("E2") And Cells(i, 4) = Range("E3") Then
    Range("E4").Resize(10, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Cells(i, 5).Resize(1, 10))
    Exit Sub
End If

Comment: But it still skips to : Next i
MsgBox "Record doesn't exist"

Comment: Ok, please answer my question, what are you trying to do? (a) Enter Name and search, (b) enter Surname and search or (c) enter both Name and Surname and search?

Comment: choose (a), (b) (c)

Comment: When I asked you to add a screenshot, I expected to see some values in cell "E2" and "E3"

Comment: Enter name and surname and then click on the existing client button assigned to the macro which should fill the other cells in column E with the data of the existing client from the data base starting at cell C17 to O17. If the name and surname does not match any in the database then it displays the message record does not exist

Comment: Not sure what I did...but the code seems to work now for some reason. Thank you so much for all your help and patience

Comment: In that case your code should work as it is. The only problem might be is that the surnames you have in your data may have characters that you do not see (extra spaces for example). Try to copy and paste the values from one of row into E2 and E3 and your code should work